# how to disable spinner click? setclickable(false) not working

Tags: android, spinner, dropdown

i want to disable dropdown list of spinner **if it have only one item**, i have almost tried everything but still i didn't get the solution, some times i got nullpointerexception while trying any solution, here is my code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,str_fname);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_childName.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(str_fname.length==1){
            sp_childName.setBackground(null);
            sp_childName.setClickable(false);
            tv_childClassname.setText(str_className[0]);
        }else{
            sp_childName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new onItemSelected());
        }
```

Comment: what is `str_fname`...?

Comment: its my string array which is i'm showing in spinner you can find it in adapter.

Comment: try calling `sp_childName.setAdapter(adapter);` in the `else` block only...no need to setdapter if spinner is disabled..

Comment: Also call `sp_childName.setEnabled(false);` ...

Comment: setEnabled(false) will make text color grey, i dont want to change text color. and i want to do it if only one item is there in spinner.

Comment: you can override the disable state color...

Comment: can you give me example i;m getting nullpointerexception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141770/discussion-between-tushar-kotecha-and-rafsanahmad007).